# Unable to select a pre-release build for release in iTunes Connect

Tags: macos, app-store-connect

I have an OSX app on the Mac app store, and I am trying to get a new version out but I have run into a very difficult to troubleshoot problem with iTunes Connect.

I have submitted builds over and over again, and there are numerous builds listed in the pre-release builds section:

[image]

However, none of these builds can be added to my pre-release version so I can submit it to the appstore:

[image]

There should be a + by **Build** to allow me to select one of my pre-release builds.

You will immediately notice that there are yellow warning triangles on all of the builds, but I cannot discover what the warning is.  If I click on any of the pre-release builds to get details, the browser just spins infinitely.  I never get any input out of iTunes Connect as to what the warning might be (if that is even the reason I cannot select the build).

I have been trying to get this submitted for 6 weeks, and iTunes Connect support is super unhelpful.  I was hoping someone here in SO might have some insight (although there isn't much to go off of).